What does "it" in "it don't" refer to?
George, unsure of its purpose, gave a package left by a
peculiar individual to his daughter Gwen:

She opens the package and finds a piece of paper with text on it.:

iN CAse it dON'T WORK ouT  -Hobie

What does "it" in "it don't" refer to?

Spider-Gwen stood up against Miguel the head of the Spider-Society. Pretty much getting herself banished and removed from the organization. This also means she lost the device that allowed her to go to other universes without glitching.
Hobie (Punk Spider-man) is a bit of a rebel and is against conforming to the rules and expected that Gwen would choose Miles over the Society, so he left one of the multi-verse devices in her own universe (entrusting it to her father) so that if "things don't work out with the spider-society" she would have a way to help her friend. (You can see him stand beside her in the final scene, showcasing he choose them over the Society).
